# How to create nested columns in sqlite in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have to insert vlaues in a table like

```
{
    "empid": "1",
    "empName": "jhon",
    "items": [
        {
            "item1": "soaps",
            "qty": "2"
        },
        {
            "item2": "books",
            "qty": "2"
        },
        {
            "item3": "sugar",
            "qty": "5"
        },
        {
            "item4": "oil",
            "qty": "10"
        }
    ]
}
```

how can I insert a column value like this in a table? using SQLite in android.

Comment: Create two table 1 .EMPID(primary table),EMPNAME 2:id,EmPID(foregin key),item,qty

Comment: Yes! Do it with multiple tables and joins.

Comment: Can you post an example for that?

Answer (score 3):

In a relational database (like SQLite) such a structure is stored in two tables. One for the Employees and one for the items. The item table has an extra column `empid` which acts as a foreign key into the employee table so that you can find out which items belong to which employee.

If the order of the items is important, you need still another column specifying the order number of the item.

Your example would be stored like this

```
empid   empName
1       jhon


empid   item    qty   ord
1       soaps   2     1
1       books   2     2
1       sugar   5     3
1       oil     10    4
```

Comment: Can I have a query for that?

Comment: SELECT item, qty FROM Items WHERE empid=1 ORDER BY ord

Comment: If there is more than one employee, then empid=? has to be dynamically generated. How to do that in a single line of query?

Comment: @Dante that really depends on your programming language and its SQL binding. For example in Java you would use a `PreparedStatement`.